# where to install postgres admin pack

Tags: postgresql

I'm using this tutorial https://library.linode.com/databases/postgresql/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin#sph_installing-postgresql on Linode to install the postgres admin pack. It says to get the postgres user and then

```
su - postgres
psql template1 < /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/adminpack.sql
```

`su - postgres` didn't work for me, but I logged in with sudo `sudo -i -u postgres` and when I tried to run the next command

```
psql template1 < /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/adminpack.sql
```

it said no such file or directory. Therefore I did

```
ls -la
```

to find out what directories and files exist and got this output, but I'm not sure how to install the admin pack from here.  Can you explain?  Thanks in advance

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 postgres postgres 4096 Jun 28 18:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 root     root     4096 Jun 28 18:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 postgres postgres 4096 Jun 28 18:32 9.1
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  194 Jul  2 03:04 .psql_history
```

Comment: Those aren't the [instructions for 9.1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).  Look for "Basic Server Setup" on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't send the sql file to the db.  Instead, simply:

```
CREATE EXTENSION adminpack;
```

It will run the sql file for you and track the objects so they can all be dropped together if needed.